# Is this URL Rewrite regular expresssion match get the same result as a string split on '/'?

Tags: php, regex, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I'm looking into replacing a PHP redirect script that splits the query string on '/' with an IIS 7 URL rewrite 2.0 rule.

Here's the code that extracts information from the request in the original redirect script:

```
list($campaign,$banner,$add_code,$deploy,$opt) = split("/",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

And here's what I think can replace that:

```
<rule name="MyRule">
   <match url="(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="TestRedirectTarget.aspx/?campaign={R:1}&amp;banner={R:2}&amp;add_code={R:3}&amp;deploy={R:4}&amp;opt={R:5}" />
</rule>
```

I'm asking if there's anything I am not thinking of in terms of the matching regex being the same functionality as the PHP string-split-assiged-to-list logic.  I found an issue such that I had to use lazy matching to handle the case that there are more than 5 pieces of slash-separated-url. I'm wondering if there's other cases where the result would not be the same.

Comment: your match expr differs wrt urls that contain the server name/address (mapping mismatch) and whose qs contains less than 5 parts (potentially no match at all).
to catch these conditions use url attributes as follows: `\?([^/]*)($|/([^/]*)($|/([^/]*)($|/([^/]*)($|/(.*)))))` -> `TestRedirectTarget.aspx/?campaign={R:1}&amp;banner={R:3}&amp;add_code={R:5}&amp;deploy={R:7}&amp;opt={R:9}"`.

Comment: very good point!  if you write this as the answer i'll mark it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your match expr differs wrt urls that contain the server name/address (mapping mismatch) and whose qs contains less than 5 parts (potentially no match at all).
to catch these conditions use url attributes as follows:
`\?([^/]*)($|/([^/]*)($|/([^/]*)($|/([^/]*)($|/(.*)))))`
    -> `TestRedirectTarget.aspx/?campaign={R:1}&amp;banner={R:3}&amp;add_code={R:5}&amp??;deploy={R:7}&amp;opt={R:9}`.